# Status bar color of BBC confused with battery low

Tags: interface, material-design, android

This morning I was reading this

[image]

Then I thought for seconds my phone battery is down. But it was not the case.  Well it is different from the red of battery saver. Many cannot figure it out. Is it good experience? As Android developer What we can do better?

Comment: The on-screen buttons help differentiate as it seems to remain black in all cases. Of course, this does now help with devices using physical buttons. I think a think red border in battery saver mode would have helped. As that's not in scope for us, I think the best we can do is use a much different shade. "Play Movies" for example uses a much darker shade of red that didn't seem confusing to me

Comment: Yeah u got my issue. And I think BBC and other number of apps should avoid it.

Comment: I don't think this is a BBC issue - it's an Android one. Android by default will change the colour of the status bar to a darker shade of the primary colour of the app being used. https://www.androidcentral.com/android-oreo-colored-notifications

Comment: Jonw let me be more clear. red status bar u can see in attached shot is at 27,% charge.

Answer (score 5):

"**But red is our BRAND!**" shouts someone from BBC's design department.

It's 2018, and by now everyone has spent a lot of time using digital applications. We've seen a lot of red things on our computer screens and they mostly are warning us that something went wrong. After a while, certain colors began to carry with them strong connotations. Just look at bootstrap, a common frontend framework, and how they connect color with meaning:

[image]

"**But red is our BRAAAAAAND!**"

Okay, yeah, red can be a brand color. But take a look at [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/yt/about/brand-resources/#logos-icons-colors). How much red is on their page? Almost none. They get that red is an especially annoying color when used excessively. They **reserve it for the moments that matter**. Also, they don't hijack the color of your status bar on Android.

[image]

"**But red is...**"

...we get it. It's easy to go overboard with color. More color means more "pop" right? And marketing people love "pop" and "flash" and making logos bigger and clawing your eyes out with whatever ploys they can devise.

According to usage studies, **red is the most attention-getting color**, which may be a reason why we use it to show that something is wrong. It's also why marketers and CEOs love using it everywhere. But **with great power comes great responsibility**.

**Don't let branding leak into universal conventions**. People use their phone more than they use a particular website, so **if your website overrides a convention that exists on their phone, users are going to get confused**.

Comment: Everything u said.. I agreed.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be kind enough to select my answer?